# Apache tries to access wsgi-rest parameters in DocumentRoot (AH01797)

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I have the following apache2/wsgi configuration, which works fine, except that apache keeps logging:

```
[info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 1 (server myserver:443)
[error] [client <IP>] client denied by server configuration: /empty/<API_CALL>
```

for every call to 'https://myserver/rest/API_CALL'

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myserver:443
  DocumentRoot /empty/ 
  <Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile    /cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /key.pem
  SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

  WSGIDaemonProcess my.api processes=2 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/API
  WSGIProcessGroup my.api
  WSGIScriptReloading On

  WSGIScriptAlias /rest /API/server.py

  <Directory /API/>
    <Files server.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      SetHandler wsgi-script
      Options ExecCGI
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is Apache trying to access something in the DocumentRoot? How can I stop this?

**Edit**
Same problem with Apache2.4:

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /empty/<API_CALL>
```

**Edit**
Updating the Access Control syntax from:

```
<Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /API/><Files server.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Files></Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /API/><Files server.py>
    Require all granted
</Files></Directory>
```

Fixed the issue.
Thx.

Comment: per your question, you're saying you're using Apache 2.4, yet your access control syntax written for httpd 2.2, take a look at examples from: [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html#run-time).

Comment: You don't say what you did with the document root unless you also had syntax errors, if you omitted it it's using the default

Comment: I would love to see you *fix* this in Apache 2.2

Comment: @Rob-d: I removed the trailing slash, but have not recognized any effect.

Comment: So did you remove document root?, I don't know why you're listing a directory simply to deny access to it

Answer (score 4):

- I'll try to cover second part of your question:

> How can I stop this?

I took following part from your question:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myserver:443
  DocumentRoot /empty/ 
  <Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Directory>
```

if `/rest/API_CALL` is the only URI that being used *and* because of `WSGIScriptAlias`, I believe my answer will eliminate following error:

> AH01797: client denied by server configuration

- by commenting out `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>`, Apache's `httpd` will take default value from main `httpd.conf` (depending on your distro and/or packaging, location could be pointing to different place, as an example I'll take commonplace such as `/var/www/html`), there is default values for `<Directory>` as well, which should satisfy `httpd` from writing an error into `error_log`.

I'd recommend test these changes in testing environment before applying to live environment.

---

Also, while answering this question, I actually learn something new myself). I think it's common mistake for manys, so I thought I'd share with everyone:

- Per [core - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot)

> The DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.

Comment: there is a need for <Directory> - it's mapping to the filesystem where the API is

Comment: @Rob-d Thank you for commenting. `DocumentRoot` does mapping, not `<Directory>`.

Comment: directory is for the script alias, we don't store code in document root.

Comment: @Rob-d Per OP question, script alias is done via `WSGIScriptAlias` (outside of `<Directory>`), also do you guys actually have `/API` in root of your file system, because if it is not, then `<Location>` should be use instead of `<Directory>`.

Comment: that's **not** the issue - location or directory it doesn't matter in this case +  he's not serving files from /API - it's not a document root

Comment: @Rob-d The issue is: `[error] [client <IP>] client denied by server configuration: /empty/<API_CALL>` and with my proposed changes, I believe error will go away.

Comment: That's the error, the issue is denying access, remember this already works!

Comment: What actually helped was Updating the access-control syntax. As suggested not in this post but in the comment of @alexus.

Comment: @x539 I'm glad my answer helped you! btw, first `<Directory>` ACL is already part of `httpd.conf` as default rule, and that's what I attempt to covered in this answer)

Comment: Oh the irony ... delicious.

Answer (score -1):

maybe I'm getting this wrong (after looking at the Apache docs, I'm now sure this is correct)- but doesn't Apache think it's serving files from DocumentRoot ? - this has nothing to do with /rest (this is your code URL) - if you are not hosting files from this virtual host then just specify the same documentroot as your default apache document root. you are calling the document root here htps://myserver:443 and then proxying to the script root /rest.

its http request > docroot > deny > scriptalias > 200

Apache has a DocumentRoot and WSGIScriptAlias is only a type of proxy, keeping your documents and code seperate.

In Summary - Apache has to have a Document root, (even when you disable the document root it will default to PREFIX/htdocs) so this is a valid and expected error, script aliases don't replace the document root but proxy off at the URL defined `WSGIScriptAlias /rest /API/server.py` --> https://server/rest.

> ServerName myserver:443   DocumentRoot /empty/
>   
>       Order allow,deny
>       Deny from all
>
> client denied by server configuration: /empty/

I think this is correct:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myserver:443
  **DocumentRoot /** 
  <Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    **allow from all**
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile    /cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /key.pem
  SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

  WSGIDaemonProcess my.api processes=2 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/API
  WSGIProcessGroup my.api
  WSGIScriptReloading On

  **WSGIScriptAlias /** /API/server.py

  <Directory /API/>
    <Files server.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      SetHandler wsgi-script
      Options ExecCGI
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Document Root is an fundamental and explicit option that you can't not have but can deny access to.

Comment: *The DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.* - `DocumentRoot /` is _WRONG_ & assuming OP is _NOT_ looking to change how application is being accessed, changing `WSGIScriptAlias` will break that.